# setTimeout doesn't work on next call

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using `setTimeout` to display a bootstrap3 progress bar. It works the first time I display it when I press submit. But when I press submit again, the progress bar doesn't start from 0 which I've tried to ensure using `setTimeout`.

I'm using the following JavaScript code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#name-form").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    $(".progress").css("display", "block");
    $(".progress-bar").css("width", "0%");
    setTimeout(function() {
      $(".progress-bar").css("width", "70%");
    }, 10000);
    var $form = $(this),
        url = $form.attr('action');

    setTimeout(function() {
      $(".progress-bar").css("width", "100%");
      $('#message-heading').append("Welcome");
    }, 2000);
  });
});
```

Why is this happening?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Title</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class='container'>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-offset-4 col-sm-4">
        <form action="/" class="form text-center" method="post" id="name-form">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" id="submit-id-submit">Submit</button>
          <div>
            <ul class='list-unstyled' id='error-list'></ul>
          </div>
        </form>
        <br>
        <div class="progress" style="display: none">
          <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class='container text-center'>
      <h3 id='message-heading'></h3>
      <p id='message-body'>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#name-form").submit(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        $(".progress").css("display", "block");
        $(".progress-bar").css("width", "0%");
        setTimeout(function() {
          $(".progress-bar").css("width", "70%");
        }, 10000);
        var $form = $(this),
          url = $form.attr('action');

        setTimeout(function() {

          $(".progress-bar").css("width", "100%");
          $('#message-heading').append("Welcome");
        }, 2000);
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: It is working fine in the demo: Press button, goes to 0, then to 100 and then 70...and same for the next click

Comment: Why you are using setTimeout for this? Note that you have first a timeout of 10 seconds and then a timeout of 2 seconds, I don't know why, but it's a bad concept I think. If you tell us what you need to make, maybe changing your code it works

Comment: @NikhilBatra Yeah I just saw that. But for some weird reason the same doesn't happen on my browser.

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude I deliberately added a 10 second timeout to test the code. If you see, the second time it doesn't wait for 10 seconds before reaching 70%. In my original code it is just 1 second.

Comment: If this code runs in snippet, but in your localhost don't works, maybe you have another code that enters in conflict. have you a URL for testing? We have to view the error to help you.

Comment: Which  browser are you using ?

Comment: it depends on how you are clicking, when you click and wait 10s it works OK - in 2s 100%, in 10s 70%. But when you click before 10s finished the first loop is still running, and then you get 70% earlier. You need to reset setTimeout with button clicking

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude Yes actually inside the second `setTimeout` there is an ajax call happening which is updating the progress bar. I removed it because I thought it may not matter. Does it?

Comment: Maybe is that @kamienok says. Or maybe the AJAX call intercepts something of the code. I don't know. Are you viewing console and network tabs of your developer tools?

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude Yes I guess what you are saying is true. I forgot these are asynchronous calls and are not happening sequentially. Maybe I'll have to change my code. Please post your comments as answer so that I can accept them. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you! I answer you with a sample code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to comments in principal post, I answer like this:
It seems that is an AJAX call to know what percent is to be pushed in the bar. I recommmend to you that uses deferred with a promise to sincronize ajax call and settimeouts.

All jquery ajax call returns a deferred that you can use like this:

```
 var def = $.ajax({ /* all your stuff*/ });
 def.done({ /* your code when ajax is finished */ });
```

There are a lot of methods that you can play with it to sincronize callings.
If you have problems with it, please, advice us and we can help you!

The deferred documentation:

https://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

When you click on submit button, you need to reset all existing (already running) timers. So you are sure, that you stop everything from previous step.

I added two timers `timer[0], timer[1]` for each setTimeout. See attached code below:

```
// after click reset all existing timers
for (var i = 0; i < timer.length; i++) {
  if (timer[i]) {
    clearTimeout(timer[i]);
    timer[i] = null;
  }
};

//set timers
timer[0] = setTimeout(function() {
  // your code
}, 10000);

timer[1] = setTimeout(function() {
  // your code
}, 2000);
```

Your updated snippet:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Title</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class='container'>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-offset-4 col-sm-4">
        <form action="/" class="form text-center" method="post" id="name-form">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" id="submit-id-submit">Submit</button>
          <div>
            <ul class='list-unstyled' id='error-list'></ul>
          </div>
        </form>
        <br>
        <div class="progress" style="display: none">
          <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class='container text-center'>
      <h3 id='message-heading'></h3>
      <p id='message-body'>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function() {
  
      //initialize timer array
      var timer = [];

      $("#name-form").submit(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        // reset all existing timers
        for (var i = 0; i < timer.length; i++) {
          if (timer[i]) {
            clearTimeout(timer[i]);
            timer[i] = null;
          }
        };

        $(".progress").css("display", "block");
        $(".progress-bar").css("width", "0%");
    
        // set first timer
        timer[0] = setTimeout(function() {
          $(".progress-bar").css("width", "70%");
        }, 10000);

        var $form = $(this),
            url = $form.attr('action');

        // set second timer
        timer[1] = setTimeout(function() {
          $(".progress-bar").css("width", "100%");
          $('#message-heading').append("Welcome");
        }, 2000);
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

setTimeout runs the function passed as the first parameter only once, for repeat them  we have to call it also at the end of the loop.

typical :

```
 function loop() {
    ..... 
    your action
    requestId = setTimeout(loop, 2000);
 }

requestId = setTimeout(loop, 2000);
```

then name your timeout function and call in way above