# How to stop a timeOut animation that contains multiple timeOut animations within

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

To start, I have an animated menu on http://www.romadev.com which I need to fix. The menu is animated with javascript/jQuery and CSS3 animations.

The problem however is that when someone quickly clicks(i.e. 3 times) on the menu button in the top left of the screen to show, hide and then show the menu, the previous animation doesn't stop playing.

This causes the menu items to animate in while the last few items are still animating out.

I have tried multiple things like a .stop() and clearTimeout. But the problem is I am a designer and not a hardcore programmer as I mostly do html, css a bit of php and a bit of javascript and jQuery.

I have googled a whole lot of examples and also found out .stop() only works for i.e. .animate() and also found out most people used the clearTimeout, but I just don't know how to implementate it and get the clearTimeout to work. So I have changed my code back to how it original was.

Here's the code for my menu:

```
$("#menu-toggle").click(function() {

    // Menu SlideDown Animation
    $("#primary-menu-container").toggleClass("primary-menu-container-visible");

    // Menu Button Icon Animation
    $("#menu-icon-top").toggleClass("menu-icon-top-active");
    $("#menu-icon-middle-1").toggleClass("menu-icon-middle-1-active");
    $("#menu-icon-middle-2").toggleClass("menu-icon-middle-2-active");
    $("#menu-icon-bottom").toggleClass("menu-icon-bottom-active");
});

// Animate Menu Items
$("#menu-toggle").click(function() {

    setTimeout(function() {

        $("#home").toggleClass('menu-item-animation');
        setTimeout(function() {

            $("#over-ons").toggleClass('menu-item-animation');
            setTimeout(function() {

                $("#cases").toggleClass('menu-item-animation');
                setTimeout(function() { // Do something after 3 seconds

                    $("#applicaties").toggleClass('menu-item-animation');
                    setTimeout(function() { // Do something after 3 seconds

                        $("#nieuws").toggleClass('menu-item-animation');
                        setTimeout(function() { // Do something after 3 seconds

                            $("#support").toggleClass('menu-item-animation');
                            setTimeout(function() { // Do something after 3 seconds

                                $("#contact").toggleClass('menu-item-animation');
                            }, 150);

                        }, 150);

                    }, 150);

                }, 150);

            }, 150);

        }, 150);

    }, 0);
});
```

So if anyone could help me by pointing me in the right direction that would be great as I really would like to understand how to use clearTimeout for this and other projects.

Your's sincerely,

Christiaan

Comment: look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31291729/settimeout-doesnt-work-on-next-call/31293324#31293324

Comment: Could you please add JSFiddle with working example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the reply Kamienok, but I finally managed to get it to work with the help of a friend of mine.

Final code I used:

```
$("#menu-toggle").click(function() {
    // Menu SlideDown Animation
    $("#primary-menu-container").toggleClass("primary-menu-container-visible");

    // Menu Button Icon Animation
    $("#menu-icon-top").toggleClass("menu-icon-top-active");
    $("#menu-icon-middle-1").toggleClass("menu-icon-middle-1-active");
    $("#menu-icon-middle-2").toggleClass("menu-icon-middle-2-active");
    $("#menu-icon-bottom").toggleClass("menu-icon-bottom-active");
});

//GLOBAL VARIABLE FOR MENU ANIMATION  
var animationEvent1;
var animationEvent2;
var animationEvent3;
var animationEvent4;
var animationEvent5;
var animationEvent6;
var animationEvent7;

$("#menu-toggle").click(function() {

    //CLEAR ALL SCHEDULED TIME OUTS FOR MENU ANIMATION
    clearTimeout(animationEvent1);
    clearTimeout(animationEvent2);
    clearTimeout(animationEvent3);
    clearTimeout(animationEvent4);
    clearTimeout(animationEvent5);
    clearTimeout(animationEvent6);
    clearTimeout(animationEvent7);

    //REMOVE CLASSES FOR MENU ANIMATION
    $('#home').removeClass('menu-item-animation');
    $('#over-ons').removeClass('menu-item-animation');
    $('#cases').removeClass('menu-item-animation');
    $('#applicaties').removeClass('menu-item-animation');
    $('#nieuws').removeClass('menu-item-animation');
    $('#support').removeClass('menu-item-animation');
    $('#contact').removeClass('menu-item-animation');

    animationEvent1 = setTimeout(function() {

        $("#home").toggleClass('menu-item-animation');
        animationEvent2 = setTimeout(function() {

            $("#over-ons").toggleClass('menu-item-animation');
            animationEvent3 = setTimeout(function() {

                $("#cases").toggleClass('menu-item-animation');
                animationEvent4 = setTimeout(function() {   // Do something after 3 seconds

                    $("#applicaties").toggleClass('menu-item-animation');
                    animationEvent5 = setTimeout(function() {   // Do something after 3 seconds

                        $("#nieuws").toggleClass('menu-item-animation');
                        animationEvent6 = setTimeout(function() {   // Do something after 3 seconds

                            $("#support").toggleClass('menu-item-animation');
                            animationEvent7 = setTimeout(function() {   // Do something after 3 seconds

                                $("#contact").toggleClass('menu-item-animation');
                            }, 150);

                        }, 150);

                    }, 150);

                }, 150);

            }, 150);

        }, 150);

    }, 0);
});
```